# How to solve OSError [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, deep-learning, invalid-argument

I am trying to create a fake webcam stream to try my deepfake in a videoconference. However, I am having a OSError [Errno 22] Invalid argument. 
I enter the following line :

```
python faceit_live.py webcam me_to_raphy
```

Here is the full error that comes out :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "faceit_live.py", line 429, in <module>
    faceit.convert(args.video, duration = args.duration, swap_model = args.swap_model, face_filter = args.face_filter, start_time = args.start_time, photos = args.photos, crop_x = args.crop_x, width = args.width, side_by_side = args.side_by_side, live = True, webcam = True)
  File "faceit_live.py", line 270, in convert
    camera = pyfakewebcam.FakeWebcam('/dev/video1', 640, 480)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyfakewebcam/pyfakewebcam.py", line 54, in __init__
    fcntl.ioctl(self._video_device, _v4l2.VIDIOC_S_FMT, self._settings)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Can you share at least part of the relevant code?

Comment: I suspect the last file is the problem and I can't find it. I can find the opt directory but the conda directory is not in the opt

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the directory?